# data is not saving in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am beginner in firebase. I tried to save data but data is not saving in firebase. No error is show. I already check my database no data is show so please check my code .
Here is my code please check it.

**....HTML Code....**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    

    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyC2Oasrzs_Bit-5weTVixfpQgM299aT708",
        authDomain: "quiz-app-781f4.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://quiz-app-781f4-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "quiz-app-781f4",
        storageBucket: "quiz-app-781f4.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "583373016469",
        appId: "1:583373016469:web:74c2c2306ac47754d03a9c",
        measurementId: "G-NCEF91E74N"
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="d1"><br/>
        <input type="text"  id="d2"><br/>
        <button onclick=getValue()>Submit</button>

      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**...JavaScript Code...**

```
function getValue(){
    
    var name= document.getElementById('d1');
      var roll= document.getElementById('d2');
      
      var student ={
        name:name.value,
        roll: roll.value
      }
      
      firebase.database().ref('student').set(student)

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code that writes to the database looks fine at first glance. If you change it to `firebase.database().ref('student').set(true)`, does it work?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you've put your inputs in a `form` tag. When you do that, the form tries to submit and reloads the page before your JavaScript executes. Removing the `form` tags solved the issue when I tested your code locally.